# A relatively useless but fun question for quants and physicists

Tags: option-pricing, arbitrage, limits-to-arbitrage

Suppose I am a trader travelling in a very fast spaceship. What kind of SDE and corresponding PDE should I jot down and work with in order to ensure that there is no arbitrage (or if there is relativistic arbitrage that I can monetise that)?

As the PDE corresponding to the usual Black-Scholes SDE is basically a Schrodinger type equation I don't think it is going to be relativistically invariant. Also, how would change of numeraire work in a relativistic setting?

Comment: Not sure about this, but on a related note, a similar question was already studied by Paul Krugman, see ["The Theory of Interstellar Trade" (1978)](http://www.princeton.edu/~pkrugman/interstellar.pdf).

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Thank you! I wasn't aware of the paper - will read it.

Comment: I think espen haug has a section on something similar in his models on models book

Comment: The main issue is likely that you can’t trade at the price you just saw and the lag to consider between the info and your order is increasing. So it probably becomes similar to derivatives on illiquid assets like funds, where you need to decide with T-1 info what orders to send on T. Apart from that because the actual markets for the derivs and the delta are in a single place, those bits surely are consistent. A maturity of 1y on earth may be only a few minutes for you though, so introducing some discounting correction may make sense. Ah, investing in a 100y bond and getting it all in 2h...

Comment: The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Theory_of_Interstellar_Trade  has some additional pointers.  Years agi I went to Espen Haug's talk in Aaron Brown's seminar at Morgan Stanley on this very issue. I can't find it online. Perhaps you should look for his "Derivatives Models on Models" book.

Comment: Actually: ["Space-Time Finance" (E.G. Haug, 2004)](http://www.espenhaug.com/SpaceTimeFLong.pdf).